# Prevent email composer from rotating iOS6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am trying to prevent the email composer from rotating to landscape when using UIActivityViewController in iOS6.  Subclassing the MFMailComposeViewController used to work in iOS5 adding methods to prevent the rotation but doesn't seem to work if I subclass UIActivityViewController and add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The methods do get called but do not do anything.

Anyone done this before?

Comment: Apple decided to completely change rotation management for iOS 6, and they've only slightly documented the changes.  It may well be that you can no longer control the email controller, other than to "pin" the entire application one way or the other.

Comment: I've managed to get it working by sub classing tab bar controlled and navigation controller in other views. This is the only one

Comment: I don't think that mechanism works for modal views.

Comment: I've managed to get it working on other modal views, it's just the one using UIActivityViewController